# How to check if jwt token is present in local storage when user navigates to /route in Next.js app

Tags: node.js, express, next.js13

I am using Next.js(version 13) for frontend and Express for backend.

Worth to mention that my server is on different port.

NEXTjs localhost:3000/ route

```
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Home() {
  const [profile, setProfile] = useState<AxiosResponse | null>(null);
  const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getProfile() {
      try {
        const authToken = localStorage.getItem("x-auth-token");
//sending token to back to verify it
        const profile = await axios.get(
          `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_URL}/api/user`,
          {
            headers: {
              "x-auth-token": "authToken",
            },
          }
        );
        setProfile(profile);
      } catch (error) {
        
      }
    }

    getProfile();
  }, []);

  if (!profile) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  console.log(profile);

  return <p>test</p>;
}
```

I confused with this client/server components in next and will appreciate if someone can write me example of how I should do that auth correctly.

I want to write reusable function which will check for jwt token in local storage and if present send to my backend to verify it.
If token is not present or not valid - redirect to localhost:3000/login

Comment: Your questions needs editing, you should check the guide on how to ask good questions so as to get answers:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot to setup for the code. I will suggest you to use some state management library like redux toolkit. This allow you to share state between your component globally.

- First you can define your function to call your backend API related to auth like login, logout, refresh your token. You can use axios or fetch for this.
- Add async thunk for each of your function. This worked as middleware for your  defined function before with redux state management.
- Define your auth slice with state you need in your component. Also bind your thunk to extraReducers in createSlice function.
- Use dispatch to trigger your defined async thunk function.
- You can add some interval function with useeffect and dipatch your refresh thunk on the root layout to refresh your token periodically

There is a tutorial that you can follow related to this:
https://blog.logrocket.com/handling-user-authentication-redux-toolkit

Since you use nextjs13, rembember that by default nextjs will using Server Side Rendering. So when you read or write your value in localstorage you need to check if currently in client side.

You can also implement middleware routing to check if the token is not exist and redirect to your login page. Here is the documentation for sample implementation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware

Comment: thx for links , but I don't need state management tool, because I don't need it